# GCloud build YAML substitutions don't work

Tags: gcloud, substitution

I have a build config file that looks like:

```
steps:
...
<i use the ${_IMAGE} variable around 4 times here>
...
images: ['${_IMAGE}']
options:
   dynamic_substitutions: true
substitutions:
   _IMAGE: http://example.com/image-${_ENVIRON}
```

And I trigger the build like:

```
gcloud builds submit . --config=config.yaml --substitutions=_ENVIRON=prod
```

What I expected is for the gcloud to substitute the _ENVIRON variable in my script and then substitute the _IMAGE variable so that it'd expand to 'http://example.com/image-prod' - but instead I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: generic::invalid_argument: key "_ENVIRON" in the substitution data is not matched in the template
```

What can I do to make that work? I really want to be able to change the environment easily with a sub and without the need to change anything in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, this isn't possible.

If the only use of `_ENVIRON` is by `_IMAGE`, why not drop the `substitions` from `config.yaml` and use `_IMAGE` as the substitution:

```
ENVIRON="prod"
IMAGE: http://example.com/image-${ENVIRON}

gcloud builds submit . \
--config=config.yaml \
--substitutions=_IMAGE=${IMAGE}
```

Comment: Well, that's disappointing but very helpful anyway. Thank you!